# How the globals are initialized before entry point?

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to figure out how Windows manages to map the memory of a PE file into the address space, so I've seen something that makes me confused.

Let's say we have something like this:

```cpp
HMODULE some_module = GetModuleHandleA(NULL);

int main() { // Or DllMain doesn't matter

    // some operations using some_module or whatever

    return 0;

}
```

The initialization of some_module is performed before entry point is called. I'm trying to implement this looking into the PE file (I found the initialization functions), but only thing I  can see is that those initialization functions are used as RUNTIME_FUNCTION, nothing else. How can I extract those initialization functions among all the runtime functions and call them manually? Are there any documentation about this? I also tried a function called `RtlAddFunctionTable` but I think it's not made for that. What kind of operations can performed to implement that? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to re-implement your CRT'a startup code? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Yeah I figured out the problem. It was just about different thing. Those entries are called in entry point, before calling DllMain or main. They're probably using a function called "initterm", to initialize the runtime functions between some memory range. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is solved, was about a different thing. But I had some research and see that those entries (runtime functions, includes static initializations) are already called in entry point. Those functions are specified as some memory range and called by a function called "ucrtbase!initterm" (or "ucrtbase!_initterm"). In some PE files that initterm function is compiled as a new function, instead of using an import from ucrtbase. And finally, those functions are called in an order of where they're located in memory (lower-address -> upper-address).

Comment: `initterm` is in no way an initializer for globals, it's just a Microsoft C++ runtime function that initializes virtual function tables. Globals require zero code to be initialized.

Comment: You're wrong. I'm talking about static initializations. Look at my example, how do you expect that it requires zero code to be initialized? And I made a research about it, they really call initterm. Sometimes it's not directly imported, but the pattern is pretty same.

Comment: @kur How would you suggest that `some_module` from the question were to be initialized and *"require zero code"* to do so?

Comment: The question (put in more readable English) is "How are global variables initialized before a Windows Portable Executable entry point?". This has nothing to do with runtime data like C++ virtual pointers or any C/C++ startup code. Globals are simply loaded from the binary with their initial values. Now if you want to ask a question about C/C++ runtime, then change the title.

Comment: @kur You are reading something into the question that's not there. Granted the question is confusing the user-defined entry point for the OS-level entry point. Still, globals that require run-time initialization are initialized at run-time. Code that is compiled to use Microsoft's CRT does so from the `initterm()` function. It does so by running all initializers that the linker has previously placed between two named sections into the PE image. This protocol is used across virtual all native language runtimes on Windows.

Comment: Well the question is indeed very confusing and the answer very incomplete. At least the word "globals" should be removed from the title.

Comment: @kur You are wrong, again. The procedure described previously is *specific* to globals that require initialization to values that aren't known at compile time. Removing *"globals"* from the question title would make it a different question, and certainly won't help making it better. Indeed, it would make it worse.

Comment: Typical global variables are known at compile time and handled by the operating system as it loads an executable, be it windows PE or Unix ELF. It boils down to copying `.data` sections from the executable. Then there is specific code added by various toolchains to perform extra setup required by specific languages, which does some extra initialization, mostly on things that are not variables to begin with (like virtual function tables for C++).

Comment: @kur Not sure why you start qualifying certain usages of globals into typical and something else. I have described what this question is asking about. I'm at a total loss why you assume that virtual function tables in C++ would require **any** sort of runtime initialization on Windows. Care to explain?

Comment: Erf... My bad, sorry. I meant a list of C++ initialization function. [`initterm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/initterm-initterm-e?view=msvc-160) is part of the Microsoft CRT library, which is not the only way of producing Windows executables (see [Delphi runtime](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_the_RTL_(Run-Time_Library)), for instance). So this question mixes up what belongs to the operating system (loading an executable file) and the Microsoft-specific way of initializing a runtime.

Comment: @kur Do you have evidence, that Delphi doesn't use Microsoft's CRT/UCRT for its startup code (and thus initialization of globals)? I find it unreasonable to assume that any language implementer would re-invent machinery already present.

Comment: Delphi's manufacturer claims to have a specific runtime. So has .Net (notably countless games written with Unity), which use WIndows PE for their DLLs and yet no CRT. Anyway, I finally got the idea behind this question. It's about the C++ possibility of initializing global variables with function calls (i.e `int globlal = func();`, not "globals" at large. The doc is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-initialization) and the code is part of the CRT, readily visible from Visual Studio (in `exe_common.inl`). Calling these functions alone would be useless anyway.

Comment: @kur Delphi's manufacturer also explicitly states that their runtime is not to be confused with the CRT, which strongly suggests that Delphi uses both. .NET assemblies require the CLR to get off the ground. Microsoft's CLR is written in C and C++, so the same principles hold. Probably more so than ever with the introduction of the Universal CRT. Mind you, that's a system component, so your entire system vs. language support library distinction starts to fall apart.

Comment: Most of the compiled code around is C++-based so counterexamples are hard to come by. Still this is just a C++ mechanism that happens to be implemented in a `ucrtbase.dll` function relying on the compiler generating some undocumented table bracketed by two symbols. Nothing to do with the Windows Portable Executable format, nor the global variables at large. It's just a support for the `global = func()` C++ syntax, as implemented by Microsoft CRT, and [explicitly documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/initterm-initterm-e) as reserved for runtime use.

Comment: @kur *"this is just a C++ mechanism that happens to be implemented in a `ucrtbase.dll`"* - That's a C support library, not C++. When things work in C, they work for *any* practical programming language. *"Nothing to do with the Windows Portable Executable format"* - Section names *are* reflected in the PE image, making this absolutely related to the PE format. *"explicitly documented as reserved for runtime use."* - If you are the vendor of a programming language (e.g. Delphi), you *are* producing the runtime, so you fall into the *"runtime use"* category.